# Copy user field value to SharePoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016, column, sharepoint-fields

I have a user field in a list that has allow multiple user setting on. ie I can have more than one user in the field. I am trying to copy my User field data form on prem SP2016 site to online site. But nothing is getting copied. Same logic is working if I am running it for two lists in same site but in case of two different sites it is not working.

Below is the code I am using :

`//To get form source list
FieldUserValue[] users = null;
users = (FieldUserValue[])item["User"];`

`//to copy on target list
 var listItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
 ListItem newItem = targetlist.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);
 newItem["User"] = users;
 newItem.Update();
 targetlist.Update();
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();`

Anyone having idea what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an article related to assigning multiple users in user and field group[here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/900b5143-f5b3-4fd5-a9ce-3e7d7c3ecfc1/csomjsom-operation-to-update-user-field-value?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Hope it will help others too.